# Counting Paths Between 2 Vertices In A Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm having some difficulties on understanding the A^2.
Wish someone could help me to understand it better maybe if possible with another example?

This is one of my slides.

> Problem: counting paths between two vertices in a graph. The number of
>   different paths of length k > 0 from the ith vertex to the jth vertex
>   of a graph (undirected or directed)
>          = (i, j)th element of Ak where A is the adjacency matrix of the graph.
>
> ```
>  My A;             A^2;
>     [0 1 1 1]           [3 0 1 1]     I'm having difficulty to understand A^2
>     [1 0 0 0]           [0 1 1 1]
>     [1 0 0 1]           [1 1 2 1]
>     [1 0 1 0]           [1 1 1 2]
> ```
>
> Adjacency matrix A and its square A2 indicate the number of paths of
>   length 1 and 2 respectively. E.g. there are three paths of length 2
>   that start and end at vertex a: a – b – a, a – c – a, and a – d – a,
>   but only one path of length 2 to c: a – d – c.

EDIT:
Let's focus on the A^2 AKA "A Squared"..I think after spending almost an hour for this..I roughly have the idea on how the thing shall work.

For Row [3][1]=1 translate how many paths does C has for it to reach A which is 1 through (c-d-a).

For Row [3][2]=1 for C to reach B, there is only 1 path (c-a-b)

For Row [3][3]=2 .There are 2 paths which is (c-a-c) & (c-d-c)

For Row [3][4]=1 .There is only 1 way which is (c-a-d)

Am i right?

So if were to be A^3 AKA "A Cubed" does it means I have to find out which source will be able to reach its destination within (x-x-x-x)?

I tried my own with A^3 based on my own understanding.

```
[2 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1]
[0 1 2 0]
[0 1 0 2]
```

Can someone please check if it is correct?Thanks alot.

Comment: It means "A squared".

Comment: So - what's the question? What don't you understand?

Comment: [That's not A^3.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={{0%2C1%2C1%2C1}%2C{1%2C0%2C0%2C0}%2C{1%2C0%2C0%2C1}%2C{1%2C0%2C1%2C0}}^3)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, may i know which part is wrong?

Comment: @BetaTracks The link goes to a Wolfram Alpha calculation.

Comment: @BetaTracks do you know how matrix multiplication works? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29 `A^2 = A * A`

Answer (score 0):

So the reason that your computation of A^3 by counting paths differs from the linear algebraic interpretation of A^3 is that you need to count paths that repeat vertices.

```
     [2 3 4 4]
 3   [3 0 1 1]
A  = [4 1 2 3]
     [4 1 3 2]
```

Consider the (1, 2) entry, which is 3. The 3 (non-simple) paths of length 3 from vertex 1 to vertex 2 are 1212, 1312, 1412.